# When did vampires first come about?

Tags: history-of, vampire

I am researching a vampire essay thing and I can not find the exact date as to when they were first seen or what the story was that first had vampires in it.

Comment: Where have you looked?

Comment: The obvious starting point is [*Dracula*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dracula), but that itself may have been based on previous literature or folklore.

Comment: Another place to look is [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vampire_literature) which mentions plenty of pre-_Dracula_ vampire literature.

Comment: The fundamental question is what vampiric tropes you require, or if you're looking for the first mention of a name or term. Do you requires your vampires to come back from the dead? Such blood? Result from improper burial practices?

Comment: possibly better asked / researched on https://mythology.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4):

It is commonly claimed that the legends of vampires come from a family of diseases know as [Porphyria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porphyria#Vampires_and_werewolves) though this comes in and out of vogue.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vampire):

> The charismatic and sophisticated vampire of modern fiction was born
>   in 1819 with the publication of "The Vampyre" by the English writer
>   John Polidori; the story was highly successful and arguably the most
>   influential vampire work of the early 19th century.[[3]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vampire#cite_note-SU373-4)

The basic idea has been around for a very long time but the entity of the Vampire as we know it comes from the 1700s([Wiki section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vampire#Folk_beliefs)):

> The notion of vampirism has existed for millennia. Cultures such as
>   the Mesopotamians, Hebrews, Ancient Greeks, Manipuri and Romans had
>   tales of demons and spirits which are considered precursors to modern
>   vampires. Despite the occurrence of vampire-like creatures in these
>   ancient civilizations, the folklore for the entity known today as the
>   vampire originates almost exclusively from early 18th-century
>   southeastern Europe,[[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vampire#cite_note-SU223-1) when verbal traditions of many ethnic groups
>   of the region were recorded and published.

Lastly, the word vampire first appeared in English in 1734

see J. Simpson; E. Weiner, eds. (1989). "Vampire". Oxford English Dictionary (2nd ed.). Oxford: Clarendon Press.

Comment: _"They based idea has been around"_ - I can't quite parse what this is meant to say, could you [edit] it? Also do you have anything more "official" than Wikipedia? It's not exactly the most reliable of sources.

Comment: I edited it. As to your concerns, [Wikipedia was found to be as accurate as the Encyclopaedia Britannica](https://www.nature.com/articles/438900a) ([This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viral_phylodynamics) article is actually published in a peer reviewed journal) furthermore everything I quoted from Wikipedia has citations if the OP wants 'more legitimate' citations